# Combining two object's records and sort by date

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I have 2 lists from different objects which I would like to combine into one in a Visualforce component.

The objects are not directly related, but both have amounts and a date which i am trying to display in one list ordered by date (like a bank statement).

Object 1 is called Delivery_Note__c, and is a child under the standard object Order. Object 2 is called Remittance_Advice__c, which is a related list directly under the standard object Account.

There is a running total, which i am using an apex:variable to calculate.

After looking at other similar posts, it looks as if i need to build a wrapper class or an sobject to store field values?

**UPDATE**
Updating the class as per David's answer, with table example...

```
public class CustomerStatementTableController {

    public Id recId {get;set;}

    public class Wrapper implements Comparable {
        public Delivery_Note__c note { get; private set; }
        public Remittance_Advice__c remittance { get; private set; }
        public String dataType { get; private set; }
        public Date calculatedDate {get;private set;}
        public decimal calculatedAmount {get;private set;}

        public Wrapper(Delivery_Note__c n) {
            note = n;
            dataType = 'note';
            calculatedDate = note.Credit_Note_Date__c;
            calculatedAmount = note.Invoice_Total_Amount_Including_GST__c;
        }

        public Wrapper(Remittance_Advice__c r) {
            remittance = r;
            dataType = 'remittance';
            calculatedDate = remittance.Date__c;
            calculatedAmount = remittance.Remittance_Total_Credit__c;

            if (Schema.sObjectType.Remittance_Advice__c.fields.Date__c.isAccessible()) {
                calculatedDate = r.Date__c;
            } else {
                calculatedDate = r.Date__c;
            }
        }

        public Integer compareTo(Object other) {
            Wrapper o = (Wrapper)other;

            // Perform some comparison logic here, such as comparing 
            // the Date properties of the embedded sObjects.
            // It may be useful to add a calculated Date property to the wrapper class to facilitate this.

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public List<Wrapper> wrappers { get; private set; }

    public CustomerStatementTableController() {
        List<Delivery_Note__c> notes = [
            SELECT id,name,order__r.AccountId,recordType.name,Invoice_Total_Amount_Including_GST__c,Credit_Note_Total_Including_GST__c,
                Invoice_Number__c,Invoice_Date__c,Credit_Note_Date__c
            FROM Delivery_Note__c
            WHERE order__r.AccountId = :this.recId
            ORDER BY Invoice_Date__c,Credit_Note_Date__c
            LIMIT 50
        ];

        wrappers = new List<Wrapper>();

        for (Delivery_Note__c note : notes) {
            wrappers.add(new Wrapper(note));
        }

        List<Remittance_Advice__c> remittances = [
            SELECT id,Name,Account__r.id,Date__c,Remittance_Total_Credit__c,Remittance_Total_Debit__c
            FROM Remittance_Advice__c
            WHERE Account__r.id = :this.recId
            ORDER By Date__c
            LIMIT 50
        ];

        for (Remittance_Advice__c remittance : remittances) {
            wrappers.add(new Wrapper(remittance));
        }
    }
}
```

And the Visualforce Component:

```
<apex:component controller="CustomerStatementTableController" access="global">

<apex:attribute type="Id" name="recordId" description="Record ID" assignTo="{!recId}" />

<table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>   
            <th style="text-align:left;border-bottom:2px black solid;padding:5px;font-size:14px;">Transaction Date {!wrappers.size}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <apex:repeat value="{!wrappers}" var="w">
        <tr>
            <td>Date: <apex:outputText value="{!w.note.Credit_Note_Date__c}"/></td>
            <td>Date: <apex:outputText value="{!w.calculatedDate}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>

</apex:component>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wrapper class is exactly the pattern you need. Basically, your wrapper will need to store the date, plus any fields you want to store from the underlying objects (or simply store the objects themselves).

Here's a very simple skeleton adapted from a [post I wrote](https://www.ktema.org/2018/02/17/everyday-salesforce-patterns-wrapper-class/):

```
public class Wrapper implements Comparable {
    public Delivery_Note__c note { get; private set; }
    public Remittance_Advice__c remittance { get; private set; }

    public Wrapper(Delivery_Note__c n) {
        note = n;
    }

    public Wrapper(Remittance_Advice__c r) {
        remittance = c;
    }

    public Integer compareTo(Object other) {
        Wrapper o = (Wrapper)other;

        // Perform some comparison logic here, such as comparing 
        // the Date properties of the embedded sObjects.
        // It may be useful to add a calculated Date property to the wrapper class to facilitate this.

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Your Visualforce can then conditionally render based on which sObject is embedded in the wrapper (you may wish to add a property to the class to make this Visualforce logic simpler).

You should decide whether you want to implement a wrapper like this, where you embed the sObjects directly and make rendering decisions in Visualforce, or implement a wrapper that simply stores a set of common attributes synthesized from the underlying sObjects without storing them at all, and then show those wrappers themselves in Visualforce.

Comment: Thanks David, love the post. I am struggling with the compare section. I have added the wrapper as per your example, using a date field as the calculated field across the two objects, however there are no results. Also, regarding the FLS, is this mandatory? in the post it mentions manual enforcement, is that by field?

Comment: (I have updated the question code snippet to incorporate this suggestion)

Comment: FLS checks are mandatory if you're submitting to the AppExchange. If you're not, it's up to you to decide if they're necessary in enforcing your own org's visibility rules. Remember that you have to `<apex:repeat>` over your list of Wrappers and then display their contents, and you may need to enclose some `<apex:outputPanel>`s that have `rendered` conditions to conditionally show one or the other child object.

Comment: Hi David. Ive tried using <apex:repeat value="{!wrappers}" var="w"> with just a date field <apex:outputText value="{!w.calculatedDate}" /> to repeat for testing, but no records are being returned?

Comment: Hi David, I'm still struggling to get this working, can you help? Thanks

Comment: Your code fundamentally looks correct, at a glance. Can you use `System.debug()` to pin down where your issue is located? Are you populating the wrapper list and getting the values you expect there? Are your queries returning values at the time you issue them?

Comment: Thanks for this David, I found the issue - The variable i am passing to the class isn't being read for some reason (:this.recId). One quick thing though before I close this question, I cant work out how to sort the results? (calculated date)

Comment: Unfortunately Apex has no notion of a keyed sort - you'd simply have to implement `Comparable` and write `compareTo()` to compare the calculated dates and return a sorting.